# Apache JMeter set MIME type to substring of json

Tags: java, jmeter

My current Apache JMeter test plan is basically a ForEach loop through a bunch of files. It has to set the MIME type of my file depending on the file extension.

E.g.

```
"fileName": "example.docx"
```

So now I could easily extract the fileName using the json extractor.

My question is how can I continue using this in order to set the MIME type using an if controller. (create a fileExtension variable, substring fileName -> if fileExtension == docx / if fileName.contains("docx") -> set MIME type to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)

Since I am new to JMeter I would appreciate any help on how to do either of those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is using i.e. [Apache Tika library](https://tika.apache.org/), if you download `tika-app.jar` and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to detect MIME types of nearly any file from any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
new org.apache.Tika().detect("example.docx")
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)